# Manipulating objects within loaded content

Tags: jquery, css

I'm loading external content into my doc as per code here. I'm having trouble manipulating css of an object within the loaded content though. On the example here the `#subContainer` ends up blue, not red. I thought it would be something relating to timing between loading and execution of the code which is why I'm using jQ `.on()` but still no result...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <style>
    #subContainer {
        width:600px;
        height:400px;
        background:blue;
    }   
    </style>

    <script src="support/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready( function() {

        var $cntnr = $('#container');
        var $subCntnr = $('#subContainer');

        $(window).on('load', function() {

            var testFunct = function() {
                console.log($subCntnr)
                $subCntnr.css({ background: 'red' });
            }

            testFunct();

        });

        $cntnr.load('parentDoc.html', function() {
            $('#subContainer').load('contents.html');
        });

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the document is loaded there is no `subContainer` element so your variable `$subCntnr` refers to an empty set.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cntnr = $('#container');

    $cntnr.load('parentDoc.html', function () {
        $('#subContainer').load('contents.html');

        var $subCntnr = $('#subContainer');
        console.log($subCntnr)
        $subCntnr.css({
            background: 'red'
        });
    });
});
```

Also AFAIK there is no `load` event triggered when using [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load contents into an element. So you need to add your dom manipulation code to the load complete callback.

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cntnr = $('#container');

    function dosomething() {
        var $subCntnr = $('#subContainer');
        console.log($subCntnr)
        $subCntnr.css({
            background: 'red'
        });
    }

    $cntnr.load('parentDoc.html', function () {
        $('#subContainer').load('contents.html');
        dosomething()
    });
});
```

Comment: would this work if inside of load callback I would only have a function call and all the code that actually needs to be executed on callback –inside of that called function (which would be sitting outside of the load/callback handle)? Does it matter if this called function is listed in code before or after the `$cntnr.load`?

Comment: not it doesn't... only think that matters is the function must be called within the load callbacl